# Error while configuring pcduino as wifi AP

Tags: linux, shell, embedded-linux

I am trying to make a pcduino as a wireless AP, while following this link http://learn.linksprite.com/wifi/make-pcduino-as-a-wireless-ap/ and everything goes well up until I reach this step:

```
for i in hostapd hostapd_cli; do cp -f $i /usr/local/bin/$i; done
```

It gives me an error `bash: do: command not found`, please help.

Comment: Did you try without the "do" command?

Comment: when i tried without the 'do' command it gave me an error about the "done" command, but after having tried without the "do" and the "done" it compiled and installed the hostapd

Comment: OK great! Just added this comment as an answer, so you can accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`do` should go on it's own line. On a single line, add a semicolon (`;`) like so:

```
for i in hostapd hostapd_cli; do; cp -f $i /usr/local/bin/$i; done
```

This is equivalent to:

```
for i in hostapd hostapd_cli
do
    cp -f $i /usr/local/bin/$i
done
```

Since there is only one statement in the `do ... done` block, you can leave out the `do` and `done` (just make sure to leave them both out), like so:

```
for i in hostapd hostapd_cli
    cp -f $i /usr/local/bin/$i
```

or equivalently (on a single line):

```
for i in hostapd hostapd_cli; cp -f $i /usr/local/bin/$i
```

More information at e.g. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html

Comment: It still brought an error, but when i tried without the 'do' command it gave me an error about the "done" command, but after having tried without the "do" and the "done" it compiled and installed the hostapd

Answer (score 0):

You can try without the `do` and `done` commands, e.g.:

`for i in hostapd hostapd_cli; cp -f $i /usr/local/bin/$i;`

Answer (score 0):

when i tried without the 'do' command it gave me an error about the "done" command, but after having tried without the "do" and the "done" it compiled and installed the hostapd –  Kikomeko Ibrahim Sep 30 at 0:08